# stemming problems in python

Tags: python, nlp

I want to find the stems of Persian language verbs. For that first I made a file containing some current and exception stems. I want first, my code searches in the file and if the stem was there it returns the stem and if not, it goes through the rest of the code and by deleting suffixes and prefixes it returns the stem. The problem 1) is that it doesn't pay attention to the file and ignoring it, it just goes through the rest of the code and outputs a wrong stem because exceptions are in the file. 2) because I used "for", the suffixes and prefixes of verbs influence on other verbs and omit other verbs' suffixes and prefixes which sometimes outputs a wrong stem. How should I change the code that each "for" loop works independently and doesn't affect the others? (I have to just write one function and call just it)

I reduced some suffixes and prefixes.

```
def stemmer (verb, file):
   with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f:   
      f = f.read().split()
      for i in f:
           if i in verb:
           return i
           else:
               for i in suffix1:      
                    if verb.endswith(i):
                        verb = verb[:-len(i)]
                        return verb
```

Comment: Can you explain the problems more clearly? adding some example may be helpful!

Comment: You are re-using the same loop variable `i` for different things in nested loops. This will probably not do what you expect. BTW, if your are working with language data, you might want to look at [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Also note that `split` only handles whitespace. It doesn't remove punctiation. Another thing you might want to look at are [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). They can help you find prefixes and suffixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. the problem is caused by "else:". there is no need to it.

```
def stemmer (verb, file):
   with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f:
      f = f.read().split()
      for i in f:
           if i in verb:
              return i




      for i in suffix1:      # ماضي ابعد
           if verb.endswith(i):
               verb = verb[:-len(i)]
               break
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put all of your code, sara. We are only concerned with the snippet that causes the problem.

My guess is that the problematic part is the check `if i in verb` that might fail most of the time because of trailing characters after splitting the characters. Normally, when you split the tokens, you also need to trim the ending characters with the `strip()` method:

```
>>> 'who\n'.strip() in 'who'
True
```

Conditionals like:

```
>>> "word\n" in "word"
False

>>> 'who ' in 'who'
False
```

will always fail and that's why the program doesn't check the exceptions at all.

Comment: if it reads the file first and then the rest of the code, the problem can be solved. how should I change the code that it first just reads the file and if the stem was there, it returns it and if not, it enters to the rest of the code for deleting the affixes?